# Change \texttt font-size

Tags: fontsize, typewriter

I would like to make `\texttt` font size smaller globally.
I am using `\usepackage[scaled=.7]{beramono}` and it works. But is it possible to use other font than `beramono` and still have the possibility to set scaled parameter?

Comment: Short answer, yes.

Comment: It depends to the font you want to use.

Comment: I would like to use some serif font, how could I do that?